# Excel formula in case of multi-column duplicates, finding them and changing values in results

Tags: excel, duplicates, excel-formula, multiple-columns

Well, I'm not an advanced user, but I will try to be specific.
Does anyone know how to do this:
I have some values in column A and some values in column B. If the values in A,B of two rows are duplicates, I need as result in column C: value of column B +1 for each row that is duplicate.

Let me explain in an example.

COLUMN A    ---- COLUMN B ----    COLUMN C (preferred result)
PD3221 ----------2012-01-04 --------      N/A ----- (because A1,B1 and A2,B2 aren't duplicates)
PD3221     ----------2012-04-25 --------      N/A ----- (because A1,B1 and A2,B2 aren't duplicates)
PD3484     ----------2010-04-27 ----   2010-04-28 (because A3,B3 and A4,B4 are duplicates)
PD3484     ----------2010-04-27 ----   2010-04-29 (because A3,B3 and A4,B4 are duplicates)
PD3484     ----------2010-05-27-----    2010-05-28 (because A5,B5;A6,B6;A7,B7;A8,B8 are duplicates)
PD3484     ----------2010-05-27-----    2010-05-29 (because A5,B5;A6,B6;A7,B7;A8,B8 are duplicates)
PD3484     ----------2010-05-27-----    2010-05-30 (because A5,B5;A6,B6;A7,B7;A8,B8 are duplicates)
PD3484     ----------2010-05-27-----    2010-05-31 (because A5,B5;A6,B6;A7,B7;A8,B8 are duplicates)
PD4880     ----------2010-04-27-----    2010-04-28 (because A9,B9 and A10,B10 are duplicates)
PD4880    ----------2010-04-27-----    2010-04-29 (because A9,B9 and A10,B10 are duplicates)

Okay, if anyone has any idea, or needs more explanation, please answer, I have over 13,000 rows to arrange like this.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by using this formula in C2

`=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)=1,"N/A",COUNTIFS(A2:A$2,A2,B2:B$2,B2)+B2)`

format C2 in required date format and fill down the column

To fill down put cursor on bottom right of C2 until you see a black "+" sign - that's the "fill handle" - double click left mouse button and the formula will populate the whole column as far as you have continuous data in the adjacent column

The formula works because the first `COUNTIFS` function counts rows where col A and col B are the same as the current row - if there is only 1 (the current row itself) then the formula returns "N/A", otherwise there must be duplicates so the second `COUNTIFS` function counts instances so far and adds that number to the date, thus incrementing the date for each duplicate as required